# WCF MaxTransferWindowSize property

Tags: wcf, binding, properties

Can I set MaxTransferWindowSize property using NetTcpBinding or WSHttpBinding??

Comment: Take a look here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733795.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MaxTransferWindowSize is related to reliable sessions, and both NetTcpBinding and WSHttpBinding support reliable sessions, so, if everything else is properly configured, then you can choose either.